# sql server equivalent of xmlelement formatting

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've written an Oracle package to query out some data to XML, as below:

```
select 
  XMLSERIALIZE(DOCUMENT 
  xmlelement("QueryResults", XMLAttributes('Demographics And Relationships' as "title"),
  xmlelement("Row",
    xmlelement("field",XMLAttributes( 'Title' as "title"),pn.title),
    xmlelement("field",XMLAttributes( 'First Names' as "title"),pn.first_names),
    xmlelement("field",XMLAttributes( 'Last Name' as "title"), pn.last_name)
  )
  ) as clob indent size = 2
) as XML
from people_names pn
```

Which returns:

```
<QueryResults title="Demographics And Relationships">
<Row>
<field title="Title">MR</field>
<field title="First Names">John</field>
<field title="Last Name">Smith</field>
<field title="Date of Birth">20/07/1990</field>
</Row>
</QueryResults>
```

I'm trying to now put together a SQL server version of the same package, but cannot get it to match the Oracle output which includes a ROW element to cover each row returned, a field tag to cover each element within the row, and an alias for the column name to be used as an attribute.

I've tried various permutations of FOR XML EXPLICIT/RAW/AUTO etc and can get some of the output required, but not all of it.  Can anyone suggest a way I can make this work with T-SQL? many thanks.

Comment: Your source query is missing the column that supplies `Date of Birth`. What's the name and type in the table? (This matters for how we format it in T-SQL.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jeroen Mostert told you already: There are more approaches to skin that cat :-)

This is my suggestion.

```sql
SELECT 'Demographics And Relationships' AS [@title]
      ,(
        SELECT 'Title' AS [field/@title]
              ,pn.title AS [field]
              ,''
              ,'First Names' AS [field/@title]
              ,pn.first_names AS [field]
              ,''
              ,'Last Name' AS [field/@title]
              ,pn.last_name AS [field]
              ,''
              ,'Date of Birth' AS [field/@title]
              ,pn.date_of_birth AS [field]
        FROM @t pn
        FOR XML PATH('Row'),TYPE
       )
FOR XML PATH('QueryResults');
```

You need the outer sub-select, because there is an attribute in the *top-root-level*. You can use `ROOT('root')` to create a root element, but no attributes are supported here. That's why we need an external `FOR XML PATH()`.

The internal list of `<field>` nodes can be achieved by a trick: Just place an empty "column" in between. This will tell the engine to close the element and to start a new one.

About your DOB: within XML any date should be ISO8601. On different systems a date like `03/12/1991` can be taken as the third of December or as the twelvth of March. Let the engine do the translations for you...

Comment: Thanks very much, this is also another excellent way to resolve the issue, indeed there are many ways to skin this skint, I unfortunately couldn't figure any of them out alone!

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way to skin this cat in T-SQL, but my preference would be `FOR XML PATH`:

```sql
DECLARE @T TABLE(
    title nvarchar(max),
    first_names nvarchar(max),
    last_name nvarchar(max),
    date_of_birth datetime
)
INSERT @t VALUES 
    ('MR', 'John', 'Smith', '1990-07-20'), 
    ('MS', 'Jane', 'Doe', '1991-12-03')

SELECT [@title] = 'Demographics and Relationships', (
    SELECT
        (SELECT [@title] = 'Title', [data()] = title FOR XML PATH('field'), TYPE),
        (SELECT [@title] = 'First Names', [data()] = first_names FOR XML PATH('field'), TYPE),
        (SELECT [@title] = 'Last Name', [data()] = last_name FOR XML PATH('field'), TYPE),
        (SELECT [@title] = 'Date of Birth', [data()] = FORMAT(date_of_birth, 'dd/MM/yyyy') FOR XML PATH('field'), TYPE)
    FROM @T
    FOR XML PATH('Row'), TYPE
)
FOR XML PATH('QueryResults')
```

Result:

```xml
<QueryResults title="Demographics and Relationships">
  <Row>
    <field title="Title">MR</field>
    <field title="First Names">John</field>
    <field title="Last Name">Smith</field>
    <field title="Date of Birth">20/07/1990</field>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <field title="Title">MS</field>
    <field title="First Names">Jane</field>
    <field title="Last Name">Doe</field>
    <field title="Date of Birth">03/12/1991</field>
  </Row>
</QueryResults>
```

Comment: This is a good approach (+1 from my side), but I prefer to avoid sub-selects with `FOR XML` due to namespace repetitions. In this case there is no namespace, but this might come later. (Or someone else with a similar issue comes here)

Comment: @Shnugo: like most people, I prefer to pretend there's no such thing as namespaces, but your point is well taken. :-)

Comment: Thank you! I'd tried some approaches using a subquery approach, but couldn't get near what you've outlined above.